# Table "Products" with predefined products, user can customize the price. How to avoid data redundancy?

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp

I've been thinking on this problem for fews days and I still can't find a way to do what I want.

Below is how my database is currently designed (it's where I'm stuck) :

[image: Database]

This is what I want :

- a User can create multiple PriceSheets. A User can give a PriceSheet any name he wants. There are two PriceSheets types : "Lab Fulfillment", or "Self Fulfillment".
- if the User chooses "Lab Fulfillment", he can import all or part of the Products of one of the predefined Labs. (I rephrase : there are few Labs that come with a predefined list of Products). The User will only be able to customize the price. He can't add custom products to this PriceSheet.
- if the User chooses "Self Fulfillment", he can add his own products, and can personalize each field (name, cost, price, dimension_h, dimension_l).

I don't know how to link the tables between them. If I put the predefined Products in the Products table and set a Many-to-Many relationship between PriceSheets and Product, the default price of a predefined Product will be overwritten when a User customizes it, which is not what I want.

Also, I want the default values of my predefined Products to be only once in my database. If 100 users uses the predefined Products, I don't want the default cost to be in my database 100 times.

Don't hesitate to ask for precisions, I had trouble making this question clear and I think it's still not totaly clear.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, database normalization 101. Lots of ways to do this, would take me a day to really optimize all this, this should help:

```
User

Lab

Product
id        name           cost          dimension   .....
1         a
2         b
3         c
4         d
```

So those three tables are fine. All your products will go in the Product table. No foreign keys in any of those tables.

```
PriceSheet
user_id   custom_price   product_id    type
1         1.99           1             lab-fulfillment
0         NULL           2             self-fulfillment
1         5.99           3             lab-fulfillment
```

So a user can have as many price sheets as they want, and they can only adjust the price of a product. This can actually be normalized further if you so wish:

```
PriceSheet (composite key on id, user_id, FK user_id)
id   user_id
0    0
1    1
2    1

LabPriceSheet (you could add an id, might be better, or you could use a composite key, stricter)
PriceSheet_id       custom_price   lab_product_id
0                   1.99           0
2                   5.99           1

CustomPriceSheet
PriceSheet_id       custom_product_id
1                   0
```

With foreign keys as appropriate. This now makes MySQL restrict the custom_price, rather than in PHP (although you would still have to deal with ensuring correct INSERT!).

Now, to deal with who adds the products:

```
CustomProduct
id    user_id    product_id    timestamp
0     3          2             ...      

LabProduct
id    lab_id     product_id    timestamp
0     0          1             ...  
1     0          3             ...
```

So let's double check:

> This is what I want :
>
> a User can create multiple PriceSheets. **check** A User can give a PriceSheet
>   any name he wants. **check** There are two PriceSheets types : "Lab
>   Fulfillment", or "Self Fulfillment". **check**
>
> if the User chooses "Lab Fulfillment", he can import all or part of the Products of one of the predefined Labs. (I rephrase : there are few Labs that come with a predefined list of Products). The User will only be able to customize the price. He can't add custom products to this PriceSheet.

Yup, because he would create a LabPriceSheet that can only add lab_product_id. Custom price is there too, that overrides the default price in product table.

> if the User chooses "Self Fulfillment", he can add his own products, and can personalize each field (name, cost, price, dimension_h, dimension_l).

Yup, he would add a product (you would need to check if a similar one exists, else return the id of the existing product in the product table), and then that would also be an entry in CustomProduct.

> I don't know how to link the tables between them. If I put the predefined Products in the Products table and set a Many-to-Many relationship between PriceSheets and Product, the default price of a predefined Product will be overwritten when a User customizes it, which is not what I want.

Yeah that won't happen :) Never (very very rarely) implement many-many rels.

> Also, I want the default values of my predefined Products to be only
>   once in my database. If 100 users uses the predefined Products, I
>   don't want the default cost to be in my database 100 times.

Of course.

Let me know if you want the MySQL code, I assume you're good! Remember to use InnoDB and properly configure your MySQL configuration!

**EDIT**
I felt like helping you out with a copy and paste thing. I like copy and paste things. Also, there's a redundant user_id column in the blurb above which I fixed in an earlier edit.

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table = 1;
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
SET GLOBAL character_set_server = utf8mb4;
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
CREATE DATABASE SO; USE SO;
ALTER DATABASE SO CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` VARCHAR(555) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARBINARY(200) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `role` INT(2) NOT NULL,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `Lab` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `Product` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARBINARY(200) NOT NULL,
  `cost` DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
  `height` DECIMAL(15, 5) NOT NULL,
  `length` DECIMAL(15, 5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `CustomProduct` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES `User`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`product`) REFERENCES `Product`(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `LabProduct` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lab` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`lab`) REFERENCES `Lab`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`product`) REFERENCES `Product`(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `PriceSheet` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  `user` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`user`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES `User`(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `LabPriceSheet` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price_sheet` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `lab_product` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `custom_price` DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`price_sheet`) REFERENCES `PriceSheet`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`lab_product`) REFERENCES `LabProduct`(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `CustomPriceSheet` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price_sheet` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `custom_product` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`price_sheet`) REFERENCES `PriceSheet`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`custom_product`) REFERENCES `CustomProduct`(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Hi Eugene! WOW, that's a hell of an answer! Thanks a lot, I'm trying to fully understand how it works. I'll get back to you if I have any further questions.